# Parse two different API response using Retrofit 2 in Android

Tags: java, android, serialization, retrofit2

I am facing a problem while parsing API response using Retrofit 2.

The API's are already in production and I cannot request a change in API.

Following are two different responses I am getting from server

Success response:

```
{
    "status":0,
    "empId":121,
    "message":"Data available",
    "data":{
        "name":"Sam",
        "designation": "Software Engineer",
        "mob": "1255565456"
    }

}
```

Failure response

```
{
    "status":10,
    "empId":121,
    "message":"No data available",
    "data":""

}
```

Parsing Classes

```
class Response{
    public int status;
    public String message;
    public int empId;
    public Student data;
}

class Student{

    public String name;
    public String designation;
    public String mob;
}
```

I am able to parse the success response. But getting the following exception for the failure case.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Answer (score 0):

The way that you can handle this situation is by treating 'data' as a generic object rather than as a String or 'Student'.

```
p̶u̶b̶l̶i̶c̶ ̶S̶t̶u̶d̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶;̶

public Object data;
```

While Using data add a check like this

```
if(data instanceof String){
   String parsedData=data.toString();
}else{
   Student parsedData= (Student) data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
 Object getrow = null;
                try {
                    getrow = this.// your object
                    LinkedTreeMap<Object, Object> tree = (LinkedTreeMap) getrow;
                    String name = tree.get(<your body>).toString()
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Student as an inner class or Response class. and Retrofit will parse the response and will give you the object.

```
    class Response
    {
        public int status;
        public String message;
        public int empId;
        public Student data;

     Class Data 
     {
     public String name;
     public String designation;
     public String mob;
     }
    }
```